# CDK deployment API Gateway - CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

If you're getting the following error when you're trying to deploy an API Gateway (in particular the Stage), you'll need to ensure you have a CloudWatch ern set up against your Account.

Blah_V1Stage (V1Stage) CloudWatch Logs role ARN must be set in account settings to enable logging `(Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: a855c5c5-b64b-4b22-85e8-703909b4c850)`

```
const cloudWatchRole = new iam.Role(this, this.prefix + "_cloudwatchrole",
{
    assumedBy: new iam.CompositePrincipal(new iam.ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com")),
    roleName: this.prefix + "_cloudwatchrole"
});
cloudWatchRole.addManagedPolicy(
    iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs'))
const account = new apigateway.CfnAccount(this, "account",
    {
        cloudWatchRoleArn: cloudWatchRole.roleArn
    });
```

Comment: Please consider splitting it into a question + answer

Comment: This is tracked here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10878

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , well… it's not a question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Answer (score 21):

Just as an update, if you are using the RestApi construct, you now just need to set `cloudWatchRole: true` in the Construct Props and CDK will do the rest.

docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.RestApi.html#cloudwatchrole